How to make a custom input device/driver appear as pointer/mouse in X11?
I created a custom input driver, that appears as /dev/input/event13 when I run sudo insmod my_mouse.ko. I gave it EV_REL and REL_X,REL_Y,and REL_Z capabilities, which is all I need for the sake testing, and evtest shows it is properly generating those events.
ls -ahl /dev/input produces the following output:
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     440 Aug  3 17:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    4,6K Aug  3 17:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     180 Aug  3 17:15 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     320 Aug  3 17:15 by-path
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 64 Aug  3 17:00 event0
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 65 Aug  3 17:00 event1
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 74 Aug  3 17:00 event10
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 75 Aug  3 17:00 event11
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 76 Aug  3 17:00 event12
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 77 Aug  3 17:21 event13
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 66 Aug  3 17:00 event2
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 67 Aug  3 17:15 event3
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 68 Aug  3 17:00 event4
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 69 Aug  3 17:15 event5
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 70 Aug  3 17:00 event6
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 71 Aug  3 17:00 event7
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 72 Aug  3 17:00 event8
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 73 Aug  3 17:00 event9
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 63 Aug  3 17:00 mice
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 32 Aug  3 17:15 mouse0
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 33 Aug  3 17:00 mouse1
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 34 Aug  3 17:15 mouse2

the device also appears under /sys/devices/virtual/input as input26:
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 0 Aug  3 17:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 0 Aug  3 17:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 0 Aug  3 17:21 input26
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Aug  3 17:00 mice


But when I type xinput, all I see is:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard System Control       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard Consumer Control     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

My input device doesn't appear in the list. What am I missing? I tried using python-evdev following the example from python-evdev#injecting-input, then I see the following:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard System Control       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard Consumer Control     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ example-device                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

i.e., the device example-device appears. The problem is that it only appears if I comment out all the python code for absolute axes, and replace that with code for relative ones, as follows:
#! /bin/python

from evdev import UInput, AbsInfo, ecodes as e
from elevate import elevate
from time import sleep

elevate()

cap = {
    e.EV_KEY : [e.KEY_A, e.KEY_B, e.BTN_0],
    # e.EV_ABS : [(e.ABS_X, AbsInfo(value=0, min=0, max=255, fuzz=0, flat=0, resolution=0)), (e.ABS_Y, AbsInfo(0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0)), (e.ABS_MT_POSITION_X, (0, 128, 255, 0)) ],
    e.EV_REL : [ e.REL_X, e.REL_Y, e.REL_Z] }

ui = UInput(cap, name='example-device', version=0x3)
print(ui)
print(ui.capabilities())

{0: [0, 1, 3],
 1: [30, 48],
 3: [(0,  AbsInfo(value=0, min=0, max=0,   fuzz=255, flat=0, resolution=0)),
     (1,  AbsInfo(value=0, min=0, max=0,   fuzz=255, flat=0, resolution=0)),
     (53, AbsInfo(value=0, min=0, max=255, fuzz=128, flat=0, resolution=0))]}

# move mouse cursor
ui.write(e.EV_ABS, e.ABS_X, 20)
ui.write(e.EV_ABS, e.ABS_Y, 20)
ui.syn()
sleep(100000)

note elevate is needed to run the script normally in vscode without running as root. the sleep statement so the installed driver doesn't get immediately uninstalled again when running from vscode.
The problem with the above result, is that example-device is appearing as a keyboard, not as a pointer/mouse. How do I get it to appear as a pointer/mouse? And why does using evdev make the device appear to xinput, while my own driver doesn't? My code is as follows (in C):
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>

int value;

struct device* dev;
struct input_dev* in_dev;

static int __init my_init(void) {
    pr_info("My Mouse: Driver installation started\n");

    in_dev = input_allocate_device();
    if (!in_dev) {
        pr_err(My Mouse: in_dev=input_allocate_device() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    in_dev->name="my-mouse";
    in_dev->phys="my-mouse";

    set_bit(EV_REL, in_dev->evbit);
    set_bit(REL_X, in_dev->relbit);
    set_bit(REL_Y, in_dev->relbit);
    set_bit(REL_Z, in_dev->relbit);
    set_bit(REL_RX, in_dev->relbit);
    set_bit(REL_RY, in_dev->relbit);
    set_bit(REL_RZ, in_dev->relbit);

    int error=input_register_device(in_dev);
    if (error) {
        pr_err("My Mouse: input_register_device(in_dev) failed\n");
        return error;
    }

    pr_info("My Mouse: Driver installation complete\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void) {
    pr_info("My Mouse: Driver removal started\n");
    input_unregister_device(in_dev);
    input_free_device(in_dev);
    pr_info("My Mouse: Driver removal complete\n");
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("mo FEAR");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("My Mouse Test");

please avoid asking why I want to do this, just let me know what I'm missing, if you know. I tried creating /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf to specify my driver name, but the file keeps getting overwritten by X11.
Update:
I realize, when I look under /sys/devices/virtual/input/input32/capabilities, which is evdev, and type cat *, I get the following output:
abs: 0
 ev: 200007
 ff: 0
key: 1 0 0 0 1000040000000
led: 0
msc: 0
rel: 7
snd: 0
 sw: 0

but when I go into my own device, and do the same, I get:
abs: 0
 ev: 7
 ff: 0
key: 1 0 0 0 0
led: 0
msc: 0
rel: 3
snd: 0
 sw: 0

There is clearly a difference at the second entry, ie ev, and the 4th, ie key. Could this be the culprit? It seems I'm only getting individual bits set. How do I set multiple bits? It seems calling set_bit(...) sequentially isn't working.
Update:
I managed to make the values equivalent. But still it doesn't appear. I even made the phys and product fields identical, still nothing.
